# Java server doen't get packs from external machine

Tags: java

Only local client can connect only to server.

Client side code:

```
public InetAddress ipAddress;
private DatagramSocket socket;

public Client()
{
    try 
    {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.ipAddress = getIpAddress();
    } 
    catch (SocketException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, 1331);
        try 
        {
            socket.send(packet);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private InetAddress getIpAddress()
{
    String ipAddress;
    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        ipAddress = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ipAddress = "null";
    }
    try 
    {
        return InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Client client = new Client();
    client.start();
}
```

Server side code:

```
private DatagramSocket socket;

public Server()
{
    try 
    {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(getIpAddress(), 1331));
        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress());
    } 
    catch (SocketException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try 
        {
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println("aa");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private InetAddress getIpAddress()
{
    try
    {
        return InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Server server = new Server();
    server.start();
}
```

I tried to off my firewall, off Windows Defender, add NAT to router.

Also i checked if port is foreign port in netstat.

The only way to work fine server is to change ipAddress of client to "localhost"

Then code is working fine.

Is there and method how can i add address to server and players can connect to server with only ip address?

Comment: You're using your own IP address. If you want to send data to the server you have to use the server's IP address.

Comment: What is the host name checkip.amazonaws.com supposed to resolve to? Have you tried binding the server to be the ip address directly? Is that host name not linked to localhost in your hosts file?

Comment: @Nehorai thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to connect the server multiple other computers, you should set the **clients** IP address to the address of the server's computer.

How to know what's the IP address of the server computer?

In the computer where the server installed:

Windows: go to CMD and then type `ipconfig` you need the `IPv4` address.

[image]

Mac: go to terminal and then type `ifconfig` you need `inet` address.